# Adding to a line a specific value from the line that comes after

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's been two days that I'm struggling to solve this issue but without a solution.

My data looks like:

```
['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1', '1516988948227']
['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2', '1516988948076']
['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3', '1516990485713']
['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4', '1516990487782']
```

The output I need is:

```
['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1', '1516988948227','1516988948076']
['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2', '1516988948076','1516990485713']
['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3', '1516990485713','1516990487782']
['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4', '1516990487782', ' ']
```

In other words I need to add to each line the value of the number in the  line that comes after. For the last line I return an empty space.

If you have any Idea how I can solve the issue please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more readable solution I think:

```
lst = [['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1', '1516988948227'],
       ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2', '1516988948076'],
       ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3', '1516990485713'],
       ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4', '1516990487782']]

for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    lst[i].append(lst[i+1][-1])

lst[-1].append(' ')

print(lst)
```

Comment: I run your code I get this error :  ----> 2     lst[i].append(lst[i+1][-1])
      3 
      4 lst[-1].append(' ')
      5 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I'm not sure `lst` is the same structure then. In you OP you gave us 4 lists. I assumed you have those 4 lists in a list and can iterate over them. The error you provide suggests that in the code you run `lst` is a list of strings and not a list of lists like in my example.

Comment: I want to think you and tell you that your code works form me. (I changed the list of strings into list of lists)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lst = [['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1', '1516988948227'],
       ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2', '1516988948076'],
       ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3', '1516990485713'],
       ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4', '1516990487782']]

res = [i + [j[-1]] for i, j in zip_longest(lst, lst[1:], fillvalue=[' ']*4)]

# [['DDD1', 'EEE1', 'AAA1', '1516988948227', '1516988948076'],
#  ['DDD2', 'EEE2', 'AAA2', '1516988948076', '1516990485713'],
#  ['DDD3', 'EEE3', 'AAA3', '1516990485713', '1516990487782'],
#  ['DDD4', 'EEE4', 'AAA4', '1516990487782', ' ']]
```

Comment: When I apply the code I get this error:   1 from itertools import zip_longest
----> 2 data = [i + [j[-3]] for i, j in zip_longest(lst, lst[1:], fillvalue=[' ']*213)]

TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: Are you copy/pasting the code I have *exactly*? This works on Python 3.6.

Comment: yes the only difference is that my data is in form of lines not a list, so I run the following code to convert it to a list: lst = []
lignes = data.split('\n')
for line in lignes:
    lst.append(line)
print(len(lst))

Comment: Looks like you have another question.. you need to get your data into a list. Please ask separately or search on SO.

Comment: In fact the output I need should not be a list

Comment: What should it be then? You can always iterate your result, i.e. `for k in res: print(k)`.

Comment: That's True thank you. If you have an idea how I can change my data to a list plz help

Comment: I have tried this but it gives me a list of string not a list of lists

Comment: Then do more research; if still stuck ask a *separate* question on how to combine strings into a list of lists..

Comment: Thank you I did that but I get this error:----> 2 data = [i + [j[-3]] for i, j in zip_longest(lst, lst[1:], fillvalue=[' ']*213)]

IndexError: list index out of range

213 is the how much list I have in my raw data and j[-3] is the value of the number

Comment: @JijiAR, OK, ask a separate question pls.